# Eclipse Indigo issue recognizing updated API class info?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Indigo (Java) for an Android project which, until very recently, targetted API level 8 (Android 2.2), and now targets API level 10 (Android 2.3.3).

The reason I needed to switch was that I desired to use the getMotionRange(int) method of the MotionEvent class, which takes a single argument -- the desired axis to get the range of.  The trouble is that, when I specify:

getMotionRange(MotionEvent.AXIS_X)

...Eclipse tells me that AXIS_X cannot be resolved to a field of MotionEvent, despite samples in the SDK showing that it is, as of API level 10.  When I open the class in Eclipse, to inspect it, it seems to believe that the class info was generated from the Android 1.5 source, which might explain the issue... but I don't know how to resolve the problem in Eclipse.

I feel that I must have missed a step, when I bumped the baseline of my project to API level 10, from API level 8, that would have caused these source references to regenerate, or something?  When I open the MotionEvent class, under the supposed Android 2.3.3 source, it shows me the 1.5 info...

EDIT: Is the problem perhaps related to the View class I'm extending? (GLSurfaceView)

Comment: Have you tried Project > Clean... and/or right-clicking on the Project and selecting Android Tools > Fix project properties?

Answer (score 0):

.It sounds to me as if Eclipse Workspace metadata or Android Development Tools (ADT) Plugin for Eclipse metadata messed up.
Perhaps try cleaning up, closing/reopening your project.
Try with a new empty workspace and import the project from there.

Also, did you try looking up the build path of you project? Maybe something is wrong there.

If none of that helps, perhaps more drastic measures are to be considered.
Like re-installing ADT or even start with new Eclipse.